# Java: How do you debug a module/jar that works as a plugin for another application

Tags: java, debugging

I know this sounds like a pathetic question and I'm sure it will get ridiculed but thats the only way I know how to describe the situation.

Scenerio : I'm creating a plugin for another java application. This application that uses the compile jar (my plugin) gets placed in the applications plugin directory. Is there anyway I can go about debugging this jar (which I have to source to) in execution of an application I do not have the source to?

I'm using Eclispe Juno as my IDE.

Comment: It is not a pathetic question. You must to download the source code and add it

Comment: Attach it in the option "Attach Source". It appears when you are debbuging over the "external code"

Comment: Just make sure you have the CORRECT source code, I once spend hours looking for a bug; turned out I had an older version of the source :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say yes, if you can start the application that you plugin plugs in into :).

`java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=4000,suspend=n myapp`
to start then in eclipse setup a remote-debugging session setting it up to connect to your app running in the java debug mode to the localhost on the port 4000

This linky will probably solve all your eclipse problems

http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-to-setup-remote-debugging-in.html